# Joining two containers of objects, adding elements if already present

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I have two containers of objects of type:

```
struct Element
{
    int A;
    int B;

    Element operator+=(const Element& rhs)
    {
        if(A != rhs.A)
            throw std::runtime_error("Not like this");

        B += rhs.B;
        return *this;
    }
};

inline Element operator+(Element lhs, const Element& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Now I would like to join those two containers like follows:

- If no other element in the target container has the same value A, insert it
- If another element in the target container has the same value A, add the already present and the new element together

I was wondering if there is an elegant solution (shorter than just having two vectors and looping over them) to this using a different container than vector.

Comment: Are your containers modified frequently? Do you often need to iterate them in-order? Whether you should switch containers or not depends on these questions.

Comment: You miss `return *this;` for `operator +=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using maps of type `std::map<int, Element>`, where the key is the `A` value ?

```
std::map<int, Element>  m1;
std::map<int, Element>  m2;

// add something in m1 e/o m2

for ( auto const & e : m2 )
 {
   m1[e.first] += e.second;
 }
```

The key point is that `m1[e.first]` return a reference to the element in `m1` with key `e.first`, if present, or create it, if not present, returning the reference to the newly created element.

The important point is to have a default contructor for Element that give to the `A` value of the newly created element a special value with the meaning "absorb the `A` value from the adding `Element`".

But can be that you can give away the `A` value in `Element` if it's only used as the key for the map.

Comment: Side-note: I believe it can be approriate to include explicit braces even for single-statement bodies like the `for` loop above, particularly in the case of SO answers where the content of the answer is prone to be used by beginners (i.e., re-inforce a practice that is less error-prone). For a discussion, see e.g. [this SE Programmer's Q&A](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/).

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/ the operator[] of map does not return a const reference but just a reference.

Comment: @MrZ - in this case, you need a reference, not a const reference, because you have to modify it (the element of `m1`). The element of `m2` (`e`) can be const because you have only to read it

Comment: That is why I was referring to your statement "returning the const reference to the newly created element", but maybe I misunderstand your answer.

Comment: @MrZ - D'oh! You're right: was an error. Corrected; thanks.